# MongoDB aggregation results

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework, aggregation

This is probably a really easy answer, but I am just not quite understanding aggregation results. Whenever I see anything about aggregation it is defined with only results, it doesn't specify where the results are going, some places make it seem like they are being directly output in the console while other places make it seem like it is being placed into a new collection or something like that. I have been working with Mongo but I've been trying to learn as I go while I'm working on things. when I actually try and use an aggregation within my own code I get nothing in the console, so since I'm not sure where the results are actually going I'm not sure if something is wrong by not getting anything in the console. the entire idea of aggregation seems straightforward, I'm just confused about where and how I can manipulate the data of the aggregation.

```
SoundSpot.aggregate([
{
$geoNear: {
 near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude , latitude ] }, 
//coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
 distanceField: "location.calculated",
 maxDistance: 200, //Meters
 includeLocs: "location.location",
 num:3 ,
 spherical: true
 }
}]);
```

Comment: Where is the code with the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: I updated the post with the aggregation code that I am running.